# Ember table do not geting updating after saving or any other operation

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am using a simple table for ember when same any record it got saved in database.

but there is no effect on table i have to click of sort icon see to changes.

Table code

```
{{#simple-table class="table table-hover" tData=refbody tColumns=headerConfig as |table|}}
{{#table.header-row as |row column|}}
    <div class="th-inner">
        {{#each (get row column) as |cell|}}
        {{#if cell}}
        <span>{{cell}} <i class="sort-arrow"></i></span>
        {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    {{/table.header-row}}

    {{#table.body as |row|}}
        {{reference-row record=row type=param action="updateEmployee"}}
    {{/table.body}}
{{/simple-table}}
```

Rout code

```
saveempRcd: function (empRcd) {

        if(this.isValidRecord(empRcd, empRcd.get('employee'))){
            this.controller.set('loader', true);
            empRcd.save().then(() => {
                this.store.unloadAll();
                return this.store.findRecord('employee-list', 1).then((response) => {
                    this.get('notify').success("Successfully saved");
                    return this.controllerFor('employee').set('cEmpData', response);
                });
            }).catch((exception) => {
                this.get('notify').alert({
                    html: this.get('errorFormatter').formatErrorNotification(exception),
                    closeAfter: null
                });
            }).finally(() => {
                this.controller.set('loader', false);
                this.transitionTo("employee");
            });
        } else {
            this.controller.set('errorMessage', empRcd.get('validations.messages'));
        }
    },
```

Comment: Please show how you use table? Are saving and table in separate routes?

Comment: `refBody` is a list of what? It is a computed or not? I list and save route both the same or not?

Comment: List of employee yes both are same

Comment: when i click on sort icon of table it got updated and show me updated result

Comment: How you pass model for saving? Actually please provide more code

Comment: @AmitEngineer could you provide a full not working [ember-twiddle](http://ember-twiddle.com)?